# laravel query where in comma delimited string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel to check if a value is in an array stored as comma delimited string, example string stored in mysql table 1,14,15,20,25

So I'm trying to add comma's at the start and end to search appropriately

```
$query = Profile::whereRaw("',' + cf_profile.sub_category_id + ',' LIKE '%,$sub_category->sub_category_id,%'");
```

Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong here, as it's returning no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($sub_category, sub_category_id) > 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately that function is only returning if the exact number is stored and not if it is in the comma delimited string. i.e. it will return a sub_category_id of 2 in mysql table but not if it is 1,15,2 (this will be skipped). I need it so it will find all occurrences, any further suggestions?

Comment: @sprintcar78a  it is working fine. Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39652/1). Better create a fiddle if you are still not getting desired o/p.

Comment: Ignore that I had $haystack, $needle NOT $needle, $haystack!! Back to the original deleted comment of thank you! :D